# Сделать одну ячейку в таблице фиксированной, а другую - заполняющую оставшееся место

Tags: html

CSS не предлагать.

Не могу добиться результата, когда две колонки в таблице, одна из них 100 px, а вторая заполняет оставшееся место по ширине.

Код:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="100px">Ячейка 1</td>
<td width="100%-100px">Ячейка 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Хитрый трюк с **100%-100px** работает, но, боюсь, только не на старых браузерах. Есть другие варианты?

Comment: попробуйте использовать display: table

Comment: Прописать display: table для таблицы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/o8drfnaq/

http://jsfiddle.net/vn5vctwn/

Comment: Откройте глаза, я писал css не предлагать, на дивах я и сам могу так сделать.

Comment: и вам не хворать

Comment: Можно даже на старых добрых флоатах: http://jsfiddle.net/o8drfnaq/1/

Answer (score 2):

Второй ячейке совсем не указывай width, она естественным образом заполнит всю осташуюся часть таблицы. И width=100px лучше заменить на width=100.